# Action restrictions in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Okay so my problem is that for my game I want my character to jump and I already have the action operational but the thing is that the user can constantly keep clicking and jumping till it cant be seen on screen, instead I want to restrict the jump so that the user can only jump twice until landing back on the ground, if anyone knows how a solution would be possible that would be great!

Comment: Can you detect when your character touches the ground again?

Comment: not sure thats pretty much what i'm asking aswell

Comment: are you using physics to do the jump?

Comment: yeah I am using physics

Answer (score 1):

You said action so I am assuming you are talking about SpriteKit. I think what you want is to check actionForKey: on the sprite running the action. This only works though if you run the action with a key.

```
if ([sprite actionForKey:@"jump"])
{
    //don't jump
}
else
{
    [sprite runAction:jumpAction withKey:@"jump"];
}
```

You will have to write your own logic for double jumping or detecting when you landed, but this should cover restricting actions.

I hope that helps.